# Tomcat 8.5.42 - Post request to the server gives error 403

Tags: tomcat

I upgraded my tomcat server from 8.5.30 to 8.5.42. The GET request is working but POST request to the server is not working. It gives 403 forbidden response

configurations are like this

Context.xml

```
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">
</tomcat-users>
```

Server.xml

`````
````<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
`````

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

```
<Connector port="9998" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           address="127.0.0.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```

````

Comment: Can you show some configuration info or code. With the given information it's hard to answer your question properly.

Comment: Configurations added in question.